# Polymer v1.2.4 - Able to tab/shift-tab to background buttons in case of backdrop element

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have upgraded my app from Polymer **v0.5** to **v1.2.4** and I have a `paper-dialog` element in the `index.html` page of my app. Also, I have a `paper-button`present in the same page.

```
<body>
    <paper-button raised>view items</paper-button>
    <paper-dialog id="agreement_dialog" modal>
          Do you agree to proceed ?
          <paper-button raised on-click="agreementAccepted" autofocus>
            I  Agree
          </paper-button>
          <paper-button raised on-click="agreementDeclined">
            I Decline
          </paper-button>
    </paper-dialog>
</body>
```

Now, the issue is when `agreement_dialog` dialog is opened with backdrop, still the user is able tab/shift-tab to the button behind the backdrop i.e. `<paper-button raised>view items</paper-button>`

Is there a way to restric this behaivour in Polymer v1.2.4 because in v0.5 this was not the case.

**NOTE:** If is set the tabindex of the `view items` paper-button to -1, then it works find, but this is kind of hackish, because I have many other buttons and icon-buttons for which I need to set the tabindex = -1 for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your best bet is to use the `with-backdrop` attribute on `paper-dialog` inherited from `iron-overlay-behavior`. For more complicated cases, it might require messing with `_focusableNodes` getter from `iron-overlay-behavior`.

[`paper-dialog: withBackdrop`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog)

[`iron-overlay-behavior`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/blob/master/iron-overlay-behavior.html):

> Set the `with-backdrop` attribute to display a backdrop behind the overlay. The backdrop is
>   appended to `<body>` and is of type `<iron-overlay-backdrop>`. See its doc page for styling
>   options.
>   In addition, `with-backdrop` will wrap the focus within the content in the light DOM.
>   Override the `_focusableNodes` getter
>   to achieve a different behavior.

Comment: but modal attribute is with-backdrop (as per the doc https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog#property-modal), which I am already using.